# Empty Arraylist JavaFX

Tags: java, string, arraylist, javafx

I have a simple method like this:

```
public ArrayList<String> getImagefromGoogleUrl() {

        total = "http://www.google.it/search?q=&hl=it&gbv=2&tbm=isch&prmd=ivnsm&ei=5qW8Vua9Dsb-Pa36h7gH&start=0&sa=N";
        String stringa = "casa";
        total = total.replaceAll("q=", "q=" + stringa);

        resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        webview = new WebView();
        final WebEngine webengine = webview.getEngine();

        webengine.documentProperty().addListener((obs, oldDoc, newDoc) -> {
            if (newDoc != null) {
                nodeList = newDoc.getElementsByTagName("img");
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    Element img = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
                    src = img.getAttribute("src");
                    resultList.add(src);
                    System.out.println("resultList è grande"+resultList.size());
                     System.out.println("resultlist vale"+resultList);
                    // System.out.println(src);
                }

            }
            else
                System.out.println("ciao");


        });
        webengine.load(total);
        System.out.println("resultList prima del return è grande"+resultList.size());
        return resultList;

    }
```

I make a query with the `webengine` Object where the string is `total`, then I put each path of the Images (the query is about image research) into an `ArrayList`. The elements are correct, but when I call the function `getImagefromGoogleUrl()` and I try to get the size , I get `[]`. A clearer example:

```
ArrayList<String> prova = getImagefromGoogleUrl();

        if(prova.size()!=0)
        {
        System.out.println("prova size is"+prova.size());
        listaimmagini.addAll(prova);
        }
```

So in this way the arraylist prova is empty, I don't understand why?

Comment: Does `resultList` contain the correct values when you `return` it from your function?

Comment: No, the print  `System.out.println("resultList prima del return è grande"+resultList.size());` before `return resultList;` return me 0. I get the correct values only inside the for cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#load%28java.lang.String%29) of `WebEngine.load` says:

> Loads a Web page into this engine. This method starts asynchronous
>   loading and returns immediately.

So you use the list when the callback which populates the list has not yet been called.

---

A solution would be to not return a list, but instead accept a `Consumer<List>` and call it once you have filled the list:

```
public void getImagefromGoogleUrl(Consumer<ArrayList<String>> consumer) {
    ...
    webengine.documentProperty().addListener((obs, oldDoc, newDoc) -> {
        ... fill list
        // no pass it to the consumer
        consumer.accept(resultList); 
    });
}
```

and use it like

```
getImagefromGoogleUrl(prova -> {
    if (prova.size() != 0) {
         System.out.println("prova size is" + prova.size());
         listaimmagini.addAll(prova);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Can you make me an example?

Comment: @user5913892 (1) you call `WebEngine.load`. (2) loading begins in another thread (3) you return from `getImagefromGoogleUrl` and see an empty list (4) loading has finished, your listener is called and populates the list but all in vain.

Comment: So, are you telling me I have to create a separate thread to populate the list?

Comment: Thank you , it works. I'm going to study your solution, I never use Consumer, so I have to learn how to use it.